# Worklight Appstore go to background

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

How to push the worklight appstore to background when an app is getting installed(in iOS). Because currently there is no indicator in ios worklight appstore client whether app is getting installed or not.

Any other possible suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of iOS. It is not possible to change the behavior (push the app the background programmatically - this must be a user-action, or show an indicator - not possible due to iOS restrictions).